# How can members of my team file a complete crash report for me to examine in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I'm the Front End developper in a project, and of course sometimes my peers try my app and it crashes. However I don't always have access to their computers to debug is there a way for them to generate a crash report I could load in Xcode? As of now we only have the log and screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in Testflight or in the store you can get the logs for users that have enabled sending diagnostic and usage information.

> Beginning with Xcode 6.3, crash logs from App Store customers running
>   at least iOS 8.3 and TestFlight beta testers can be found in the Xcode
>   Organizer. To obtain these crash logs:
>
> 1) Open the Organizer window in Xcode 6.3 and above
>
> 2) Select "Crashes" at the top. The available crash logs can then be
>   found within this window.
>
> The App Distribution Guide contains further information about the
>   Crash Reporting service.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html)

Comment: We're not quite there yet :) Any other way?

Comment: Testflight is very good for these purposes, at a minimum it makes keeping everyone up to date easier. Are your colleagues running on actual devices?

Comment: Yes, but they test on a day to day basis.

Comment: That documentation also shows how to email crash logs from the device without Testflight but I really recommend you it a try. Deploying to multiple devices for testing on a daily basis is a real pain. Unless you're building a web based app and are using something like Ionic Deploy.